# Providing workspace to tfsbuilds at Runtime

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild, workspace

I am trying to automate deployment of multiple components through single TFSbuild.proj file. As part of this automation,  I was planning to supply workspaces created externally which had similar mappings at runtime, but seems like TFS doesn't seem to like that.

Is there a way where we can supply the TFS workspace name to the build at runtime. I used the variable "workspacename" and the workspace that i created is under different owner but set as public.

Can someone please help.

SK

Comment: Clarify the question: the problem is passing a string parameter to the build (workspace name) or not finding the workspace given its name?

Comment: I want the TFS build to use the workspace that i want it to use, that already has there decided mappings, but what it does is. it just takes the name and creates its own workspace mapping.

Comment: i am thinking of trying this out today ... To provide an default workspace and change the mapping with workfold command under "AfterInitializeWorkspace" target. I am not sure if that will work, but i am gonna try ..

Comment: But why do you want to manage the workspace yourself?

Comment: i am trying to build different solutions through single tfsbuild.proj file. These solution have different sourcecode mappings, hence i wanted to manage it.